# Bootstrap columns MD-6 not one row - joomla

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, joomla

I have an issue maybe with Joomla SP page builder. I created a row, then 2 columns MD-6, but they are not in one row.

Thanks for help.

See on: https://stodolaklatovy.cz

[SP page builder's columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCkVr.png)

Solution:
In cocoon.preprocess.js is `$('.sppb-row').removeClass('sppb-row');` Just commented.
Joomla NRG template.

Answer (score 1):

your are missing class `sppb-row`

```
<div class="sppb-container-inner">
  <div class=""> 
   <div class="sppb-col-md-6"></div>
   <div class="sppb-col-md-6"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried to add class="row" before I wrote here, but it isn't solved issue. :-( https://stodolaklatovy.cz/screenrow.jpg

Comment: is class row exist on you css? or i am assuming sppb-row? you could create one 

.row {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}

Comment: Great, sppb-row is the solution!

Comment: Good to here :) can you select my answer as correct ill edit row to sppb-row

Comment: oh, i found the issue. In templates javascript is:  `$('.sppb-row').removeClass('sppb-row');` *facepalm*

Comment: :) good to hear you can also update your post or answer the fix to his :)